# Color scale domain not displaying correctly

Tags: colors, d3.js

I am having some trouble with applying a colour scale on circles on a scatterplot.

What I did to set up the scale was:

```
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(d3.extent(dataset, function (d) { return parseFloat(d.Weight); }))
            .range(["#D6F5D6", "#ADEBAD", "#84E184", "#5BD75B","#32CD32"]);
```

And then apply the color to the circles with:

```
.attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.Weight) }
```

But from the graph I can tell that the colours are not correct, in fact I see some values that are higher that have a lighter colour. I think the problem is that the values get read like strings, and in fact if I do the console log, the values that are not the `min` or `max` appear as strings, and I believe that this is the problem why I get wrong color values.
I tried also to set every `d.Weight` as a number in the domain, like so:

```
dataset.forEach(function (d) { d.Weight = +d.Weight; });
```

But it doesn't work either. Attached here's an image of what I'm getting:
The X Axis is set to the Weight, so the colour of the points should be from lighter to darker going left to right, but it clearly isn't:
[image]

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT** Forgot to mention that i tried with `scale.linear()` but with it I get this result:
[image]
Just the first values get picked by the circles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordinal scales work differently from linear scales in that no interpolation between domain elements is done. To quote the documentation:

> The first element in values will be mapped to the first element in the output range, the second domain value to the second range value, and so on.

This means that your input values are being mapped incorrectly, as you're only using min and max to set up the domain. For your purposes, you probably want a linear scale.

When using a linear scale, you'll have to tell D3 how to interpolate the values of the output range, e.g.

```
.range(["#D6F5D6", "#ADEBAD", "#84E184", "#5BD75B","#32CD32"])
.interpolate(d3.interpolateRgb);
```

Note that in this case, you also need to provide the same number of input values as output values:

> Although linear scales typically have just two numeric values in their domain, you can specify more than two values for a polylinear scale. In this case, there must be an equivalent number of values in the output range.

In your case, it would be easiest to simply take the min and max and the two extreme colours.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to add that if I set the scale as linear, the circles get coloured all of the first color on the scale, so I thought that ordinal was correct... I'll add a screenshot of the linear scale output

Comment: Unfortunately I tried before with the interpolate in hsl & lab but didn't work, there's no color change in the circles even with interpolateRgb. If you'd like to have a look at the complete code here's a link to it: http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37967455/prova_dropdown_assi.html

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of using just the extreme values for the scale, now it's working properly!